# What is the difference between auto and decltype(auto) when returning from a function?

Tags: c++, c++14

I rarely see `decltype(auto)` but when I do it confuses me because it seems to do the same thing as `auto` when returning from a function.

```
auto g() { return expr; }
decltype(auto) g() { return expr; }
```

What is the difference between these two syntaxes?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`auto` follows the template argument deduction rules and is always an object type; `decltype(auto)` follows the `decltype` rules for deducing reference types based on value categories. So if we have

```
int x;
int && f();
```

then

```
expression    auto       decltype(auto)
----------------------------------------
10            int        int
x             int        int
(x)           int        int &
f()           int        int &&
```

Comment: But what if I did `auto&& x = 5` then it would be `int&&` but if I do `decltype(auto) x = 5` it would still be `int&&`.

Comment: @templateboy: no, the latter would just be `int`. Only xvalues become rvalue references.

Comment: @templateboy: If you're just declaring a variable, `auto` is by far more useful (e.g. if you have `auto &&` for a universal reference). `decltype` is useful when you mainly want to operate with *types* (not variables), e.g. in traits that check if some expression has a certain type.

Comment: Does `decltype(auto)` also maintain cv-qualification?

Comment: @templateboy: Yes, it's always the type of the expression, possibly with references added. If the expression is a CV-qualified value, that's retained. For details, see 7.1.6.2/4 ([dcl.type.simple]).

Comment: What about if `f()` returned an int. Would `decltype((f(x)))` return `int &&`?

Comment: @soandos: No, then it'd be `int`. Only xvalues, not prvalues, become rvalue references.

Comment: @KerrekSB Then the question would be when to use decltype(auto) and when just auto? Is there a rule of the thumb for each case?

Comment: @Zingam: Use `auto` when you want to return a prvalue, and `decltype(auto)` when you want to forward the returned expression preserving its value category. The latter is more subtle and needs careful thinking about, and usually comes up in generic code only. The former may reasonably be used in leaf code.

Answer (score 24):

`auto` returns what value-type would be deduced of you assigned the `return` clause to an `auto` variable.  `decltype(auto)` returns what type you would get if you wrapped the return clause in `decltype`.

`auto` returns by value, `decltype` maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, when used as function return:

- `auto` **potentially** drops cv-qualifiers and references.
- `decltype(auto)` preserves cv-qualifier and reference-ness.

For example:

```cpp
decltype(auto) func(int& x) // Equivalent to `auto& func(int& x)
{
return x;
}

decltype(auto) func(int&& x) // Equivalent to `auto&& func(int&& x)
{
return std::move(x);
}

decltype(auto) func(const int& x) // Equivalent to `const auto& func(int& x)
{
return x;
}

auto& func(const int& x) // Equivalent to `const auto& func(const int&x)
{
return x;
}

template <typename T>
auto func(T &&x) // Equivalent to `T func(T&& x)
{
return x;
}
```