# How can I write a function template that returns either a reference or a value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I'd like to write a function template that returns either a reference or a value depending on some compile time expression.  What I've tried so far is something like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto&& Func()
{
  if constexpr (some_compile_time_expression)
  {
    return GetReferenceFromSomewhere();
  }
  else
  {
    return GetValueFromSomewhere();
  }
}
```

This works fine for all types of references but doesn't work for values.  For example, if `GetValueFromSomewhere` returns a `Foo`, then the compiler deduces the return type of `Func` as `Foo&&` and warns that I'm returning the address of a temporary.

Is there any way to make this work, or am I forced to tease the two branches apart somehow (through function overloads or some such)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`decltype(auto)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21369113/241631) for the return type placeholder, it will preserve the exact value category of the function you're calling in the `return` statement

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) Func()
{
  if constexpr (some_compile_time_expression_dependent_on_T)
  {
    return GetReferenceFromSomewhere();
  }
  else
  {
    return GetValueFromSomewhere();
  }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08fe80e8904c1aed)

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you, kindly.

Answer (score 5):

Pretorian's answer is perfect, but you may also want to learn about `std::conditional`, which has broader usage. For example, consider a `data_` member variable of type `int` and a member function, that returns `data_` either by reference or by value depending on some compile-time condition:

```
template <bool COND>
std::conditional_t<COND, int&, int> data() { return data_; }
```

This would not be achievable with `decltype(auto)`. You can also use the same technique to pass arguments to functions by reference/value:

```
template <bool COND>
void f(std::conditional_t<COND, int&, int> param);
```

Or, you can switch between copy/move constructors:

```
class X {
    X(std::conditional_t<some_cond, const X&, X&&>) = default;
    X(std::conditional_t<some_cond, X&&, const X&>) = delete;
    ...
};
```

Etc...

Comment: I did make an attempt to use `std::conditional`.  It was not pretty.

Comment: @PeterRuderman Your case is different, since the return type is determined by the return type of functions you invoke internally. That's where `decltype(auto)` is by no doubt the best solution.